# (Brahma Sutras)why is a ruling Lord necessary for aggregation of the material world?

Tags: gods, philosophy, brahma-sutras

So I've been reading the commentaries by Ramanuja and Shankara on the Brahma Sutras and they say that a ruling lord is necessary for the aggregation of atoms, especially into material skandhas.

how and why would a ruling lord be necessary for the aggregation thereof?

couldn't Reality just be a shared imagining caused by avidya as the vijnanavadins say?if not why not and why would a ruling lord be necessary ?so atoms wouldn't actually exist and be aggregated by necessity?

Comment: if there is no bond between to atoms then how would it cojoins who is the binding force here, that he.. the binding force of all molecules or atoms that is he, sprituality starts when scientific process of investigating and deriving cosmic behaviour as well as atomic or weak electromagnetic or quatam mechic is stopped.. otherwise you give 1000 of theory for the world that behaves and generate of thousand of equation and some how all the equation will fail in one or the other

Comment: The reason why is in the Brahma Sutras...